# Using max() on a list that contains numbers and strings

Tags: python, string, list, int, max

I have a list that is like this:

```
self.thislist = ['Name', 13, 'Name1', 160, 'Name2', 394]
```

Basically the list has a name and a number after it, and I'm trying to find out the highest number in the list, which is `394`. But for some reason, it picks a name as `this`.

```
      if max(self.thislist) > 150:
            this = max(self.thislist) # so this should be 394
            position = self.thislist.index(this) # The index of it
            temponary = position - 1 # This is so we can find the name that is associated with it
            name = self.thislist[temponary] #and this retrieves the name
```

and it retrieves for example, `'Name'`, when it should be 394.
So the point is to retreive a name and a number associated with that name. Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you using a list for what appears to be a mapping? `self.thisdict = { 'Name': 13, 'Name1': 160, 'Name2': 394 }`.  Then `name = max(self.thisdict, key=thisdict.get)`.

Comment: I don't know, really. I never studied python or any languages, so I don't know what is the best way to do what function. So in this instance, I just decided to use list. An another function appends a name and value into a list, and this func reads it correctly. It works, and that's enough for me.

I'll lookup mapping, though. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By calling `max`, you're asking it to compare all the values.

In Python 2.x, most values can be compared to each other, even if they're of different types; the comparison will be meaningful in some arbitrary and implementation-specific way (in CPython, it mostly comes down to comparing the names of type objects themselves), but that's rarely if ever useful to you.

In Python 3.x, most values of unrelated types can't be compared to each other, so you'd just get a `TypeError` instead of a useless answer. But the solution is the same.

If you want to compare the numbers and ignore the names, you can filter out all non-numbers, skip every even element, use a `key` function that converts all non-numbers to something smaller than any number, or almost anything else that avoids trying to compare the names and the numbers. For example:

```
if max(self.thislist[1::2]) > 150:
```

---

As a side note, using data structures like this is going to make a lot of things more complicated. It seems like what you really want here is not a list of alternating names and numbers, but a dict mapping names to numbers, or a list of name-number pairs, or something similar. Then you could write things more readably. For example, after this:

```
self.thisdict = dict(zip(self.thislist[::2], self.thislist[1::2]))
```

… you can do things like:

```
if max(self.thisdict.itervalues()) > 150:
```

Comment: +1 for your sidenode.  makes me wish I had tried to figure out what OP is actually trying to do with that code before I posted my answer ... :-)

Comment: Thanks, it was this simple.

Answer (score 3):

In Python 2, you *can* compare values of different types (and they will then be compared by the *name* of the type. Since `str` comes after `int`, any string will compare higher than any integer. Since this doesn't make any sense, Python 3 has wisely removed this feature)

In order to get what you want, use a custom `key`:

```
>>> thislist = ['Name', 13, 'Name1', 160, 'Name2', 394]
>>> max(thislist, key =  lambda x: x if isinstance(x, (int, long, float)) else 0)
394
```

(This assumes that there is at least one positive number in the list)

Answer (score 2):

That's because string always compare greater than integers in Python 2. You can use a custom key function to fix that:

```
>>> lst = ['Name', 13, 'Name1', 160, 'Name2', 394]
>>> max(lst, key=lambda x: (isinstance(x, (int, float)), x))
394
```

Answer (score 1):

you'll want to filter the strings out of the list first as values of different types have and arbitrary (but consistent) ordering (in python2.x) as can be checked easily:

```
>>> 'foo' > 1
True
```

I'd just filter with a generator expression that only pulls out the numbers and pass that to `max`:

```
import numbers
max(x for x in self.thislist if isinstance(x, numbers.Number))
```

demo:

```
>>> lst = ['foo', 1, 1.6, 'bar']
>>> max(x for x in lst if isinstance(x, numbers.Number))
1.6
>>> lst = ['foo', 1, 1.6, 2, 'bar']
>>> max(x for x in lst if isinstance(x, numbers.Number))
2
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
>>> thislist = ['Name', 13, 'Name1', 160, 'Name2', 394]
>>> names, numbers = thislist[0::2], thislist[1::2]
>>> max(zip(numbers, names))
(394, 'Name2')
```